# When calculating using partition show 0

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have trouble composing special query and would be grateful if somebody helped.

I made query looking like this:

```
select distinct 
    date, time, 
    case 
       when status_id = 5 and flag = 1 then 'autoprocessed' 
       when status_id = 5 and flag = 0 then 'manually processed'
       else 'other state' 
    end as "state", 
    count (distinct doc_id) over (partition by date, time, 
                                  case when status_id = 5 and flag = 1 then 1 
                                       when status_id = 5 and flag = 0 then 2 
                                       else 0 end)
from 
    journal
```

Now my results look like this:

```
17.06.16 00:00:00   19  other state     2
17.06.16 00:00:00   19  autoprocessed   3
18.06.16 00:00:00   14  other state     1
20.06.16 00:00:00   14  other state     1
20.06.16 00:00:00   21  other state     2
21.06.16 00:00:00   15  other state     2
-----------------
```

but I would like to see them more like

```
17.06.16 00:00:00   19  other state        2
17.06.16 00:00:00   19  autoprocessed      3
17.06.16 00:00:00   19  manually processed 0
18.06.16 00:00:00   14  other state        1
18.06.16 00:00:00   14  autoprocessed      0
18.06.16 00:00:00   14  manually processed 0
----------------
```

Is it possible? I know that regular count can show zeros, even for groups. What about count with partition?

Edit: sample data

```
date                flag staus_id
17.06.16 19:32:45   0     5
17.06.16 19:33:39   0     5
17.06.16 19:34:31   0     23
17.06.16 19:37:25   0     5
17.06.16 19:42:19   0     1
18.06.16 14:33:19   0     1
20.06.16 14:35:55   0     10
20.06.16 21:24:22   0     2
20.06.16 21:24:47   0     2
-------------------
```

as you can see, at 17.06.16, 19 hours, there are 3 "autoprocessed" doucments (flag = 0, status_id = 5), 2 documents in "other sate" (staus_id <> 5) and 0 "manualy processed documents" (flag = 1, status_id = 5) which gives me first 2 strings of results:

```
17.06.16 00:00:00   19  other state     2
17.06.16 00:00:00   19  autoprocessed   3
```

Comment: leave out `else 0 ..` or use `else null` to avoid counting those cases.

Comment: Some sample data will be useful in understanding the problem.

Comment: Move your count cases to your query. Then partition.

Comment: one way would be to create a temp table with all the combinations (including 0) and join it to the results you are getting now.

Comment: Do you want to fill in other blanks as well? I.e. if there are no results at all for a given date/time combination would you still want 3 rows all showing 0s? The general scheme would be to use existing tables or synthesize them to represent all of the axes which should be fully populated, cross-join the axes and then left join that result to your existing query, using `COALESCE(<result column>,0)` in the final result set to generate the zeroes.

Comment: Damien, if you would make your proposal as answer I'll mark it as accepted. It helped me in another similar task.